# filesystem value_type pointer to string?

Tags: c++, string

I have a `directory_iterator` and I want the filename but I can't seem to get anything to work, it just throws an error saying that `value_type*` cannot be converted into a `string`.
I can't cast it to a string and `std::to_string()` doesn't work either!

```
for (auto& p : std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir)) {
    auto path = p.path().filename().c_str();

    //this doesn't work
    std::ifstream comp("Json/" + path, std::ifstream::binary);

    //neither does this
    char f[50] = "Json/";
    std::strcpy(f, path);
    std::ifstream comp(f, std::ifstream::binary);
}
```

Comment: You can't concatenate C-strings with `operator+`.

Comment: "doesn't work" - is a bad problem description. You should exactly describe the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`range-for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop uses an iterator to enumerate a sequence of elements, dereferencing the iterator on each loop iteration to access the next element in the sequence.

When a [`filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_iterator) is dereferenced, it yields a [`filesystem::directory_entry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_entry), which has a [`path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_entry/path) method (and a conversion operator) for retrieving a [`filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path) which the entry represents.

In your example, `p.path().filename()` returns a new `filesystem::path` and then its [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/native) method returns a `const char*` on Posix systems, or a `const wchar_t*` on Windows. You can't concatenate a `const char[]` (from the string literal `"Json/"`) with a `const char*` or `const wchar_t*` using the `+` operator. And `strcpy()` should have been `strcat()`, otherwise you would be overwriting the `"Json/"` that you initialized `f` with. And you can't construct a `std::string` from a `const wchar_t*` (but you can from a `const char*`).

However, `filesystem::path` has an [`operator/`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/operator_slash) for concatenating 2 path segments with a platform-appropriate separator between them.

And `std::ifstream` (and `std::ofstream`) has a constructor that accepts a `filesystem::path`.

So, try something more like this instead:

```cpp
for (auto& p : std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir)) {
    auto path = p.path().filename(); // NOTE: not c_str()! 
    std::ifstream comp("Json" / path, std::ifstream::binary);
}
```

If you want a path in string format, `filesystem::path` provides several methods for returning various string encodings, eg:

```cpp
for (auto& p : std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir)) {
    auto path = p.path().filename().string(); // NOTE: not c_str()! 
    std::ifstream comp("Json/" + path, std::ifstream::binary);
}
```

Comment: If I want to use ifstream does it begin where the file is or does it start at C:\ and also, does it use \ or /?

Comment: @SomeRandomCoder `Json/filename` is a relative path, so it opens the file relative to the calling process's working directory. As for `/` vs ```\```, that is platform-dependant. Which is why you should utilize `filesystem::path` and its `operator/` to handle the differences for you.